# how to format date for logstash filter

Tags: date, filter, logstash

i have a problem about how to format logstash input.

i have string like `testtest|2017-08-12 16:08:54,877`, it's from logstash input, currenly,

my filter like below:

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{content}\|%{DATA:create_date}"
        remove_field => ["message"]
    }
    date {
        match => ["create_date", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
    }
}
```

finally, the create_date is still a string, so how can i convert it to a date type?

Comment: solved. need  `   date {
        match => ["create_date", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"] 
        target => "create_date" }`